# ParserError in Solidity 0.8.1, works in 0.6.4

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, remix

I am trying to create ERC20 token in Solidity 0.8.1
in this function i'm getting Parser error don't know why

its working perfectly in 0.6.4 but getting error in 0.8.1 v

```
  function setMinbalance(uint256 minimumBalanceInfinney) public onlyOwner {
            
       minBalanceForAccounts = minimumBalanceInfinney * 1 finney ;
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The finney and szabo denominations are removed. They are rarely used and do not make the actual amount readily visible. Instead, explicit values like `1e20` or the very common `gwei` can be used.*

Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/070-breaking-changes.html#expressions

---

**Solution:**

Replace `1 finney` for `1e15` (because 1 finney == 1000000000000000 wei).

```
minBalanceForAccounts = minimumBalanceInfinney * 1e15 ;
```